# Using VBS script to fillout an online form

Tags: vbscript

So I have a really annoying set of forms at work that I have to fill out daily and spend about 20 minutes doing so, I was looking to script this and have a basic sendkeys method that works but I wanted to improve this.

```
Dim WshShell, objIE, ElementCol
Dim LinkHref

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Webpage Title"
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

wshShell.AppActivate objIE

Do While objIE.Busy
wscript.sleep 100
Loop

Set ElementCol = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Link In ElementCol
If Link.innerHTML = "*Specfic text" Then
Link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
```

So I get an error on the Set ElementCol line that says null thats my first issue

For the *specific text is this allowed? Basically I know the text of the links will be Hello and world but could pop in like 1) Hello and 2) World or 1) World 2) Hello

I also want to after the click run a different .vbs script that fills out the form after that .vbs script completes it returns back to this initial page where I want to continue on this script to the next link.

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: What about ReCaptcha? Do you have any way to bypass it?

Comment: Theres no recaptcha since its an internal page